# Rails 3 Getting different request from same url depending on action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes

I am creating an ajax request and building the url as follows:

```
    function submitYear(year){
    new Ajax.Request('update_make/'+year, { method: 'get'});
}
```

When I am at the new action for my car_infos controller, http://localhost:3000/car_infos/new this Ajax request works fine.  I get a request that says:

Started GET "/car_infos/car_infos/update_make/2011"

The route matches up and all is well.  However, if there is an error in the create the url becomes http://localhost:3000/car_infos and then when my ajax request triggers I get this with a routing error:

Started GET "/update_make/2002" 
No route matches "/update_make/2002"

Here is what happens in my controller when create fails:

```
format.html { render :action => "new" }
```

I understand why I am getting the routing error, because I don't have a route set up as /update_make/.  Here is my route.

```
    match 'car_infos/update_make/:year', :controller => 'car_infos', :action => 'update_make'
```

So two questions.

1. Why does my get request change when the url changes from car_infos/new to car_infos
2. How do I resolve this so when I create the url in the javascript it works for both cases?  I don't think putting a route for /update_make is the answer.  If I redirect to /new then I lose the field values and the error message.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're sending your ajax request to a relative path, so if your browser location path changes the request path changes too.  The browser location path could be changing because of a redirect in Rails or in javascript.

   Is this a typo (the 2x "/car_infos")?

   > Started GET "/car_infos/car_infos/update_make/2011
2. You could spell out the absolute url in your javascript:

   ```
   function submitYear(year){
       var absoluteUrl = 'http://' + window.location.host +
                           '/car_infos/update_make/' + year;
       new Ajax.Request(absoluteUrl, { method: 'get'});
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the information as well as the code.  I had a javascript function that was parsing the url and constructing different urls based on the result.  This is much cleaner.  (yes I must have copied the get from when I put car_infos in the url and was on new.)